# my Website loss packet in 70% countries, how can i dertermine why its loss packets?

Tags: php, networking, web-hosting, packets, packet-loss

I'm not friendly with networking so that why i post here and want to know from my seniors.

I check my website on google page speed tester, it show result 90/100
i check my website on pingdom it show good result there.

but now i find new tool that show major countries and there result.
when i check my website in [http://cloudmonitor.ca.com](http://cloudmonitor.ca.com/en/ping.php?vtt=1383102182&varghost=www.collectioncoupons.com&vhost=_&vaction=ping&ping=start)

it show good result in 30% countries and all other countries it show packet loss (100%)

My question is how we can determin why my website loss packets?

and what is its solution?

is this problem from my server or from my website?

.

i create new html blank page and set it too my index page, after it i test again , and still result show packet loss, its mean this problem is not in my website.

Here is snapshot.
and here is [live result](http://cloudmonitor.ca.com/en/ping.php?vtt=1383102182&varghost=www.collectioncoupons.com&vhost=_&vaction=ping&ping=start)

my domin: http://www.collectioncoupons.com

[image]

Update:
when i visit my website in browser website is working fine.
but when i test my domain or IP 198.178.123.219 in command Prompt its show "Request time out"

Why time out in command promt?

what is this problem?

Comment: That's something I would ask to your hosting company. If it does the same with a blank page, I don't think the program or the server configuration are the cause of your problem. Try superuser.com too .

Comment: this seems off-topic but I don't know what to close it for.

Comment: This question will get better response at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: i post my question on superuser.com, and also i see same question on superuser.com, and people comment there,"superuser is not right place for this question." .. now lets i try serverfault.com..